# Make GravityView plugin filter by Gravity Form field

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I created a form with Gravity Forms, in the form I added choice field (dropdown) and created a function in functions.php to automatically populate this field with all users usernames, the point of this is that admin want to use this form to submit entries for specific users only.

I found that GravityView plugin has the ability to filter entries and show only specific entries to specific users, for example using GravityView - Advanced Filter Extension you can filter by the creator of this entry, this can be used in case you want only users to be able to see their entries, but what I want is to enable users to see admin entries depending on the dropdown value
so if the dropdown value "username"="logged-in user" then show if not don't show
here the file where I think the changes should be made to enable this: 
https://github.com/tinbot-development/ciew-advanced-filter/blob/master/advanced-filter.php

specifically between line 295 and 336, to turn the value from created_by to the username field value

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're referring to.
http://docs.gravityview.co/article/291-how-to-allow-a-user-to-edit-all-entries

You'll need the Members Plugin installed.